# SQL расширить запрос

Tags: sql

Есть запрос который выбирает уникальные записи для каждого заказа и сортирует начиная с самой ранней по дате.

```
SELECT distinct on ("orderId") * WHERE "status" = 0 ORDER BY "orderId", "id" ASC
```

Нужно расширить запрос так чтобы выгребал такие же данные но учитывал бы что в рамках заказа у заказа нет записей с `"status" = 1`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `from tablename foo where ... and not exists (select 1 from tablename bar where bar.status = 1 and bar."orderId" = foo."orderId")`

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Изучите и выполните пункты 5 и 3.